# Updating data in Mongo sorted by a particular field

Tags: mongodb, performance, sorting

I posted this question on Software Engineering portal without conducting any tests. It was also brought to my notice that this needs to be posted on SO, not there. Thanks for the help in advance!

I need Mongo to return the documents sorted by a field value. The easiest way to achieve this would be running the command `db.collectionName.find().sort({field:priority})`, however, I tried this method on a dummy collection of **1000** documents; it runs in **22ms**. I also tried running `db.collectionName.find()` on the same data, it runs in **3ms**, which means that Mongo is taking time to sort and return the documents (which is understandable). Both tests were done in the same environment and were done by adding `.explain("executionStats")` to the query.

I will be working with a large amount of data and concurrent requests to access DB, so I need the querying to be faster. My question is, is there a way to always keep the data sorted by a field in the DB so that I don't have to sort it over and over for all requests? For instance, some sort of update command that could sort the entire DB once a week or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-unique index with that field in this collection will give the results you're after and avoid the inefficient in-memory sorting.